# Iphone OS 4.0 : Application is not coming applicationDidBecomeActive 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have recently switched my application to SDK 4.0. Now i am compiling my application with SDK 4.0 with deployment target OS 3.0. and i have facing a strange issue/bug.

Some times when my application resumes from background. it does not calls the applicationDidBecomeActive method .... is anyone else facing the issue ?

what is the solution for this ?????

Comment: Are you sure your application has not been killed in the background ? iOS 4 kills background inactive apps when it needs memory.
You may want to see if your launching event has been fired.

Comment: i m not sending application in background. if i just lock my device by pressing the sleep button and unlock quickly . it does not come in applicationDidBecomeActive ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me too - Until I realized the call is being made to AppDelegate_iPhone, so you need to forward it to its super, AppDelegate_Shared.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more success with the 
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification / UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification notifications.

Make sure to wrap your observer subscriptions with:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
{
    ... 
}
```